# Finding the correct expression for a square-wave wavefunction with time dependence

Tags: proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, wave-equation

`First some background information:`

Eigenstates of the momentum operator with eigenvalue $p$ are given by
$$\phi(p,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\exp\left(\frac{i \, p x}{\hbar}\right)\tag{1}$$

Consider a square-wave wavepacket at time $t = 0$:

$$\psi_S(x)=\begin{cases}B\exp\left(\frac{i\, p_m \,x}{\hbar}\right) & -a/2 \lt x \lt a/2\\ 0 & \qquad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

> The **momentum** representation amplitude $a_S(p)$ is:
>   $$\begin{align}a_S(p) &=\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\phi^*(p,x)\psi_S(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\&= \frac{B}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\exp\left(\frac{-i\, p\, x}{\hbar}\right)\exp\left(\frac{i\,p_m \,x}{\hbar}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\&=\frac{B}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\exp\left(\frac{-i\,(p-p_m) \,x}{\hbar}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\&= \frac{B}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}\frac{\sin\left[(p-p_m)a/(2 \hbar)\right]}{(p-p_m)/(2 \hbar)} \end{align}\tag{3}$$

---

`Now here is my question:`

> If there is no potential acting, write down an expression for the wavefunction $\psi_S(x, t)$ as an integral involving $a_S(p)$. Is the square-wave shape preserved after $t = 0$ ? (You need not perform the integral.)

---

`Here is my attempt at the question:`

The question is asking me to write the following integral incorporating time dependence $e^{-i\,E \,t /\hbar}$ and using $E=p^2/(2m)$ along with $(1)$ and $(3)$:

$$\begin{align}\psi(x,t)
&=\int \color{red}{a_S(p)}\color{#085}{\phi(p,x)}\color{blue}{\exp\left(\frac{-i E\, t}{\hbar}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}p \\ &= \int \color{red}{\frac{B}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}\frac{\sin\left[(p-p_m)a/(2 \hbar)\right]}{(p-p_m)/(2 \hbar)}}\color{#085}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}{\exp\left(\frac{i \, p x}{\hbar}\right)}\color{blue}{\exp\left(\frac{-i\,p^2\,t}{2 m \hbar}\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}p \\
 \end{align}$$

I have color coded the parts of the integrand corresponding to the factors in the the first integral above.

---

`But the problem is that the correct answer is:`

> *Answer: Unseen*
>   Momentum eigenvalues and energy eigenvalues are identical for the free particle, and each evolves with time-dependence $e^{-i E t / \hbar}$ with $E = p^2/2m$:
>   \begin{align*}
>      \psi(x,t)
>   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}
>      \int
>        a_S(p) e^{+ ipx/\hbar} e^{-i p^2 t/(2 m \hbar)}
>      \,\mathrm{d}p  \\
>   &= 2 \hbar B
>      \int
>        \frac{\sin[(p-p_m)a/(2\hbar)]}{p-p_m}
>        e^{-ipx/\hbar}
>        e^{-i p^2 t / (2 m \hbar)}
>      \,\mathrm{d}p
> \end{align*}
>   This is *not* the inverse transform of the $\operatorname{sinc}$ function, due to the presence of the $e^{-i p^2 t / (2 m \hbar)}$ factor, so it’s not a square wave.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8IVp.png).

---

This was a 2013-2014 past exam question for a quantum mechanics exam from Imperial College London.

Would I would like to know is how they managed to reach the final expression for $\psi(x,t)$. Firstly, I cannot figure out why there is a minus sign in front of the argument of the complex exponential for the momentum eigenstate. How did this happen?

Also, there were **two** factors of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$ so why isn't there a factor $\pi$ in the denominator? Instead they put a $2\pi B$ in front of the integral which makes no sense to me.

Could someone please help me understand how they reached the final expression for $\psi(x,t)$?

Many thanks.

Comment: The exponent sign is a typo.  A missing factor of $\pi$ hardly matters in the effective conclusion.